# is this possible through CSS3? or would I need javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys I just started messing around with hovering and images and pretty excited to have learned this.

I actually came on a problem with CSS3

I was wondering if all the other images can remain in tact without moving when I hover over them. Ive tried looking for something in CSS3 but nothing came out.

I have an image hovering up to 200px width and height. I was wondering if all the other images can stay fixed when the images get larger.

anyhow this is my CSS

```
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding 0px;
}
body{
  background-image: url('http://pxwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/barcelona-black-new-wallpaper-94.jpg');
  background-size:cover;


}

#container{
  width: 900px;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 60px auto;
  overflow:auto;
}


img.size{

  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  -webkit-filter:grayscale(90%);
  opacity:0.4;

}

#container ul{
  margin:70px 30px 6px 10px;
}

#container li{
  float:left;
  margin: 30px;
  list-style-type:none;
  cursor:pointer;
}



#container img:hover{
  filter:grayscale(0%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  opacity: 2;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

and my HTML

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <title>
  </title>
  <body>


    <div id="container">

      <ul>
                <li><img class="size" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRnNn3yg1C8fjtxGOHRLfYWRGnd-jsxPc8eZrd
                rVfYtm4P73YEm9w"></li>
                <li><img class="size" src="http://kodiakherbal.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/canmore_rocky_mountains-hd-wallpaper.jpg"></li>
                <li><img class="size" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRnNn3yg1C8fjtxGOHRLfYWRGnd-jsxPc8eZrdrVfYtm4P73YEm9w"></li>
                <li><img class="size" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRnNn3yg1C8fjtxGOHRLfYWRGnd-jsxPc8eZrdrVfYtm4P73YEm9w"></li>
                <li><img class="size" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRnNn3yg1C8fjtxGOHRLfYWRGnd-jsxPc8eZrdrVfYtm4P73YEm9w"></li>
                <li><img class="size" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRnNn3yg1C8fjtxGOHRLfYWRGnd-jsxPc8eZrdrVfYtm4P73YEm9w"></li>

      </ul>


    </div>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is also my site http://codepen.io/willc86/pen/BrEmt

Answer (score 1):

Here is the change you could make that would affect the least: change the hovering images margins so that the flow stays the same:

```
#container img:hover{
  filter:grayscale(0%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  opacity: 2;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin: -50px; /*this will make the image seem to be 100px by 100px*/
}
```

Here is a working version of your site: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dsblw It just has the one line change `margin: -50px`.

Comment: I'll leave my answer up but I prefer yours!

Answer (score 1):

I'd give your `li` the same width as the initial images and then ad `position:abolute` to the hover pseudo class

```
#container li{
  float:left;
  margin: 30px;
  list-style-type:none;
  cursor:pointer;
   width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

#container img:hover{
  filter:grayscale(0%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  opacity: 2;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ecuby

Comment: That makes them pop to the left and downward. I'm sure he want them coming out equally in all directions. Centered.

Comment: @DamienBlack I wouldn't make that assumption, I'm just working off th OP example where they expand in that manner but move the surrounding elements and fixing it so the other elemetns don't move. Your solution is more apealing to me though.

Answer (score 1):

I would make the `li` be `position:relative` and have `width` and `height` of the image.

The `img.size` should be `position:absolute` and on hover adjust its size and margins to center it.

Using absolute positioning and removing it from the flow allows for many effects like transitions on the resize
**Demo at** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EisIK

---

Also `opacity` goes from 0 to 1 .. so using 2 is the same as 1

---

Alternatively you could just use `transform:scale(2);` which does not affect the flow..
**Demo at** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jkapL

Comment: The alternative won't work in chrome or safari unless you also add -webkit-transform:scale(2);. IE9 requires -ms-transform:scale(2).